# How to check/validate with Google Tag Manager, whether form is empty before submission?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Im trying to check whether my signup form is already fill/not empty before submission. If it's empty than it wont count as a conversion.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have this done is to get a developer to manually add an event on form submit.

Alternatively, you could create a custom javascript variable that checks for valid inputs.

For example (its not great):

```
  function () {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('input')['Email'].value;
  if (x.includes('@')) {
    return true;
  }
    else {
      return false;
    }
}
```